# Visual Studio Code cannot configure correctly

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, eslint

For some reason, most likely because I do not know how to configure Visual Studio Code. We are talking about the free light version.

It is always showing an error of some type. I am new to this product, *not* Visual Studio Code, but this version of it.

How do we set this IDE up correct to work with it?

Here is my current error.

```
    Downloading and configuring the .NET Core Debugger...
Telemetry is: Enabled
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\Erik Little\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-0.3.7\coreclr-debug\project.json...
info : Committing restore...
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: C:\Users\Erik Little\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-0.3.7\coreclr-debug\project.lock.json
log  : C:\Users\Erik Little\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-0.3.7\coreclr-debug\project.json
log  : Restore completed in 585ms.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\Erik Little\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-0.3.7\coreclr-debug\NuGet.config

Feeds used:
    https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    https://www.myget.org/F/coreclr-debug/api/v3/index.json
Telemetry is: Enabled
Error: Can not find runtime target for framework 'DNXCore,Version=v5.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
Error: 

System.InvalidOperationException: Can not find runtime target for framework 'DNXCore,Version=v5.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
   at Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.BuildWorkspace.GetRuntimeContext(ProjectContext context, IEnumerable`1 runtimeIdentifiers)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Publish.PublishCommand.<>c__DisplayClass71_0.<SelectContexts>b__1(ProjectContext c)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Publish.PublishCommand.TryPrepareForPublish()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Publish.PublishCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Run>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Publish.PublishCommand.Run(String[] args)
dotnet exited with error code 1
Error while installing .NET Core Debugger.
```

They make it seem so easy to set up, but there is always something that I am missing. I have a very good thought that I am not setting up the configuration file correctly, because it looks strange to me. It looks like all JavaScript.

---

Also if I point to a folder that I work in without any issues at all with [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) Enterprise edition, I always get this error

```
eslintrc-error
```

It keeps looking for **`eslintrc`**, but I have looked everywhere to resolve this.

I've posted a snapshot of this issue as well.

I know it must be a configuration issue.

I do not even know what `eslintrc` is.

What should I do?

[image: eslintrc-error]

Comment: [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio) are two ***completely*** different things (thanks, Microsoft Marketing). Visual Studio Code ***isn't*** a new version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a linter for ECMAScript... the rc file configures its options.

So you're aware Visual Studio Code is an editor, not really an IDE. If you're looking for a free version of *Visual Studio*, I'd suggest [Visual Studio Community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017).

Comment: I've got the enterprise edition of VS 2015, i just though this was a light weight quick down a dirty way of working with files of all types.

Comment: It is, but you'll have to get used to the linters and other extensions that you have installed.

I'd suggest you try `Extensions: Show Extension Recommendations` (accessed with `CTL-p`) and see what's available, what you'd like to use.

Your configuration file is indeed a JSON file. You'll have to keep in mind that this is _not_ using the Visual Studio shell: it's a completely new editing environment, with a different engine, sets of extensions, the whole kit and kaboodle.